# Query all salary details employees OCA Fusion HCM

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to obtain all employee salary details. My experience in Oracle Cloud is limited and I have mostly used MSSQL instead of Oracle SQL. However, my attempt is this:

```
SELECT P.Person_Number,
       A.Effective_Start_Date AS StartDateAssignment,
       SAL.Effective_Start_Date AS StartDateSalary,
       SAL.Salary_Amount,
       A.Assignment_ID,
       AR.ACTION_REASON AS Reason
FROM Per_All_Assignments_f A
  INNER JOIN CMP_SALARY SAL ON SAL.Assignment_ID = A.Assignment_ID
  INNER JOIN Per_People_f P ON P.Person_ID = A.Person_ID
  INNER JOIN Per_Action_Reasons_TL AS AR ON AR.ACTION_REASON_ID = SAL.ACTION_REASON_ID
```

This code is incorrect (missing keyword error). Can anyone give me some tips?

Thanks a lot!

KR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code all you have done wrong is that you have entered word 'AS' on your las INNER JOIN line command before the alias.
I believe this will work :

```
SELECT P.Person_Number,
       A.Effective_Start_Date AS StartDateAssignment,
       SAL.Effective_Start_Date AS StartDateSalary,
       SAL.Salary_Amount,
       A.Assignment_ID,
       AR.ACTION_REASON AS Reason
FROM Per_All_Assignments_f A
  INNER JOIN CMP_SALARY SAL ON SAL.Assignment_ID = A.Assignment_ID
  INNER JOIN Per_People_f P ON P.Person_ID = A.Person_ID
  INNER JOIN Per_Action_Reasons_TL AR ON AR.ACTION_REASON_ID = SAL.ACTION_REASON_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. There was another slight mistake, since the SAL table does not have an Effective_Start_Date column.

Comment: But I could not see that because I do not have the info abvout the tables. Please if this helped you can mark my answer as correct and give it an up vote. If you want that is :) hehe You are welcome !